# Stability of convergence of series through multiplication

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asking myself the following question. Can we characterize the set of all sequences $(s_n)_n$ tending to $0$ so that if $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence whose series converges then the series $\sum_{n}s_n x_n$ converges too? I easily proved that this set contains $\ell^1$ but that's all...

Answer (score 0):

No. If $s_n$ is any sequence tending monotonically to $0$, for example, then [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) together with the convergence of $\sum x_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum s_nx_n$.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  This proves in particular that  $(\frac{1}{n})_n$ works but the same idea shows also that $s_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is not an option here since $(x_n)_n$ can be taken as $(\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)})_n$. It is not clear for me if this can be generalized to all alternate sequences belonging to $\ell^2$ for example?